# Entidades JPA no se guardan correctamente

Tags: java, jpa

Tengo las siguientes entidades, todas ellas relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "site")
public class Site extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6249200015501840399L;

    private String name;

    private Boolean template;

    @OrderBy("id")
    @Where(clause = "deleteDate is null")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Ceremony> ceremonies = new HashSet<Ceremony>();

    @OrderBy("orden")
    @Where(clause = "deleteDate is null")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "site", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SiteFloor> floors = new HashSet<SiteFloor>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "site_floor")
public class SiteFloor extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7377030638076319589L;

    private String name;

    private Integer orden;

    @Lob
    @Column(length=65000)
    private String map;

    private Boolean template;

    @ManyToOne
    private Site site;

    @OrderBy("orden")
    @Where(clause = "deleteDate is null")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "floor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SiteRow> rows = new HashSet<SiteRow>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "site_row")
public class SiteRow extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -197546085868764752L;

    private String name;

    private Integer orden;

    private Boolean template;

    @ManyToOne
    private SiteFloor floor;

    @OrderBy("orden")
    @Where(clause = "deleteDate is null")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "row", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SiteChair> chairs = new HashSet<SiteChair>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "site_chair")
public class SiteChair extends BaseEntity {

    /**
     * Serial
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5188420274496228482L;

    private String name;

    private Integer orden;

    private Boolean temp;

    private Boolean blocked;

    private Boolean template;

    @ManyToOne
    private Entidad entity;

    @ManyToOne
    private SiteRow row;

}
```

Y tengo un método que crea a todos los hijos y mi intención es guardarlos todos en cascada (en otras palabras guardar el padre y que automaticamente se creen los hijos), el método es el siguiente:

```
private Site nuevoSitio(Site siteTemplate, SiteService siteServ){

        Site newSite = new Site();

        newSite.setId(null);
        newSite.setTemplate(false);
        newSite.setName(siteTemplate.getName());
        for(SiteFloor siteFloor : siteTemplate.getFloors()){
            SiteFloor sf = new SiteFloor();
            sf.setId(null);
            sf.setTemplate(false);
            sf.setName(siteFloor.getName());
            sf.setOrden(siteFloor.getOrden());
            sf.setMap(siteFloor.getMap());
            sf.setSite(newSite);
            for(SiteRow siteRow : sf.getRows()){
                SiteRow sr = new SiteRow();
                sr = siteRow;
                sr.setId(null);
                sr.setTemplate(false);
                sr.setOrden(siteRow.getOrden());
                sr.setFloor(sf);
                for(SiteChair siteChair : sr.getChairs()){
                    SiteChair sc = new SiteChair();
                    sc.setId(null);
                    sc.setTemplate(false);
                    sc.setOrden(siteChair.getOrden());
                    sc.setTemp(siteChair.getTemp());
                    sc.setBlocked(siteChair.getBlocked());
                    sc.setEntity(null);
                    sc.setRow(sr);
                    sr.getChairs().add(sc);
                }
                sf.getRows().add(sr);
            }
            newSite.getFloors().add(sf);
        }

        return siteServ.saveOrUpdate(newSite);
    }
```

El problema está que al guardar, crea correctamente el primer hijo, SiteFloor, pero el resto, SiteRow y SiteChair no los crea. ¡Acaso no funcionan las cascadas con tantos elementos anidados?

Comment: Entiendo que se guarda `newSite` y el primer `siteFloor` de la iteración?

Comment: Ahora mismo se guarda newSite y todos los siteFloor que estén relacionados

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dentro del ciclo   `for(SiteFloor siteFloor : siteTemplate.getFloors()){` creas un `SiteFloor` nuevo en cada iteración, pero no veo por ningun lado que tengas `sf.setRows(var);`

Parece que el problema es que cuando llega al segundo ciclo se encuentra con una colección vacia que tu creaste en los [POJOS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)

```
    @OrderBy("orden")
    @Where(clause = "deleteDate is null")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "floor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<SiteRow> rows = new HashSet<SiteRow>();
```

**Y no se itera nada**

Tip, usa

```
 SiteFloor sf = null;
 for(SiteFloor siteFloor : siteTemplate.getFloors()){
        sf = new SiteFloor();
```

en vez de

```
 for(SiteFloor siteFloor : siteTemplate.getFloors()){
        SiteFloor sf = new SiteFloor();
```